# Collection tracker in Excel 2017

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to create a collection tracker in Excel.

I have a cell named `ACCOUNT STATUS` where I will display `PAID` or `NOT PAID`, and also a cell named `COLLECTION STATUS` where I will display `OVERDUE` or `NOT OVERDUE`.

The part where I am having problem is that on the cell named `COLLECTION STATUS`, I wanted to display `---` if the `ACCOUNT STATUS` cell displayed `PAID`.

Here is my code:

```
=IF(AND(DATEDIF(Sheet1!$A3,NOW(),"d")>F3,J3="PAID"),"---",IF(AND(DATEDIF(Sheet1!$A3,NOW(),"d")<F3,J3<>"PAID"),"OVERDUE","NOT OVERDUE"))
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please explain the logic you want. Maybe make a table, with conditions on the left, and the desired output on the right?

Comment: updated formula. still has error i got #N/A when the answer is overdue 
=IF(AND(DATEDIF(Sheet1!$A3,NOW(),"d")>F3,J3="PAID"),"---",IF(AND(DATEDIF(Sheet1!$A3,NOW(),"d")<F3,J3="PAID"),"---",IF(AND(DATEDIF(Sheet1!A3,NOW(),"d")<F3,J3<>"PAID","NOT OVERDUE",IF(AND(DATEDIF(Sheet1!$A3,NOW(),"d")>F3,J3<>"PAID","OVERDUE","NOT OVERDUE"))))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your formula for "Collection Status" is fully working with the exception that it doesn't display "---" whenever "Account Status" is "paid", then you can just modify your formula for "Collection Status" to this:

```
= IF(<account status cell> = "PAID","---",<your existing formula>)
```

Comment: OMG .. that was so simple. THANK YOUUU SOOO MUCH.. now i can sleep.